# Should we [catalog] it as burninated?

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

On the 281 question [catalog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/catalog)ed under this tag :

Most of them, 102 are related to [magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/magento) and the others are sparsely distributed to different [e-commerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/e-commerce) related question, software and functionalities some software name [catalog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/catalog).

To the look of it there is no clear use of this tag and I cannot see how someone could be an expert in [catalog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/catalog).
The tag don't even have a [wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/catalog/info)

Should we burn it ?

Comment: There's a few more tags that could burn in there as well...anyone taking any action on this tag should be advised to be on the lookout for 'em.

Comment: @Makoto I couldn't agree less [tag:products], [tag:checkout], [tag:cart], [tag:stock] are all so broad that they should never be added as tags in the first place.

Comment: cart needs to go to shopping-cart.